# Project Class 'App\Application\Model\Slider' not found after uploading

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My project worked fine on localhost, but once it was uploaded to a Linux shared host, I got the following error.

> Class 'App\Application\Model\Slider' not found

This problem occurred in three of my models: `sections, projects, Slider`. The other models work fine.

**HomeController.php**

```php
namespace App\Application\Controllers;

use App\Application\Model\Page;
use App\Application\Model\projects;
use App\Application\Model\section;
use App\Application\Model\Slider;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->except(['getPageBySlug', 'welcome']);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('website.home');
    }

    public function getPageBySlug($slug)
    {
        $page = Page::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        if ($page) {
            return view('website.page', compact('page'));
        }
        return redirect('404');
    }

    public function welcome()
    {
        $sections = \App\Application\Model\section::limit(3)->orderBy('id')->get();
        $project = \App\Application\Model\projects::limit(3)->orderBy('id')->get();
        $sliders = \App\Application\Model\Slider::get();

        return view('website.welcome', compact('projects', 'sections', 'sliders'));
    }
}
```

Comment: In your welcome() method, the $project variable needs to be plural: $projects.

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces are loaded through an autoload file. When you push to your shared hosting, you'll likely have to run 'composer dump-autoload' in the project root to compile this file.